# Visible based on 2 different Data Cards

Tags: powerapps-forms, multiple-values

I have 2 Data Cards.

Updated the "Visible' property for my field to:

```
If(DataCardValue1.Selected.Value="New" || DataCardValue2.Selected.Value="Yes, true, false)
```

`DataCard3` message with a Button will be visible based on the 2 Data card selections.

This isn't working. Can anyone help with the formula? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are these controls: `DataCardValue1` and `DataCardValue2`? Drop down or combo box? Make sure "New" and "Yes" values are correctly available in drop down options (case-sensitive). Add screenshot to your question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the `Visible` property to:

```
DataCardValue1.Selected.Value = "New" || DataCardValue2.Selected.Value = "Yes"
```

No need to add `If` and `true/false` as the condition is already a boolean.